# How do we choose a good string for the pumping lemma?

Tags: automata

we have a Language $$\mathscr L: \{a^mb^n: m \ne n\}$$

we need to choose a good string $w$.

apparently $w = a^{n+1}m^{n}$ is not a good string.

can someone explain why?

I also found this and I thought this is highly misleading, because when I use this I get wrong answers.

How to Use the Pumping Lemma
for Regular Languages
When you are given a language L and are using the pumping lemma to
prove that it is not regular, do this: : :

1. Assume L is regular.
   If it is, then the P.L. would apply. So, there is some n such that any
   string longer than n, say the string x, can be broken up into substrings
   u; v;w such that
   juvj  n | which means the pumping part, v, lies within the rst
   n characters
   jvj > 0 | which means there is at least one character in v
   uvw is the string x
   And uvmw is also in L for any m  0 | that is, pumping at v
   won't take the string out of the language.
   The key observation is that this is true for any suciently long x. You
   will pick a particular one from which you can get a contradiction.
2. Choose some string longer than n, where n is the (unknown) value
   guaranteed to exist by the P.L.
   Choose this string with a view to what you're about to do, so you can
   pump it up and derive a contradiction.
3. You know v is within the rst n characters, so take your string and
   pump it up (or de
   ate it) to get a new string.
4. Show that this new string is not in L.
   Since the P.L. says it is in L if L is regular, it must be the case that L
   is not regular.
5. You are done. Celebrate.

Comment: You mean $w = a^{n+1}b^n$, don't you?

Comment: You have to use the pumping lemma or you just think that it will be useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To apply the pumping lemma to show that some language $\mathscr L$ is not regular, you play a game like this:

1. Mr. Pumping Lemma gives you a pumping constant $p$.
2. You pick a string $s$ of length at least $p$.
3. Mr. Pumping Lemma divides $s$ into three parts $uvw$, subject to the restrictions that $|uv|\le p$, $|v|\ge 1$.
4. You now "pump" the $v$ part by picking an integer $i\ne 1$ to select a word $uv^iw$.  If $uv^iw$ is *not* in $\mathscr L$, you win.    But if $uv^iw$ *is* in $\mathcal L$, you lose.

$\def\a{\mathtt{a}}\def\b{\mathtt{b}}$Here we want to show that $\mathscr L = \{a^nb^m\mid m\ne n\}$ is not regular.  Mr. Pumping Lemma gives us $p$.  Then in step 2 I think you want to pick $s=a^{p+1}b^p$.  You ask why this is a bad move.

It is a bad move because then in step 3 Mr. Pumping Lemma can choose $u$ to be some, but not all of the `a`s; say $u=\a^k, v=\a^{p+1-k}, w=\b^p$.

If he does this, then in step 4 you need to pick $i$ so that $uv^iw\notin\mathscr L$.  But it's not at all clear what $i$ to pick. Once you've picked $i$, you get $uv^iw = \a^k\a^{i\cdot{p+1-k}}\b^p = \a^{k+i(p-1+k)}\b^p$.

Now this string does have the form $\a^m\b^n$, where $m=k+ik+ip-i$ and $n=p$.  So to win, you need $m=n$, so $ k+ik+ip-i = p$.  Solving for $i$, we get $i = \frac{p-k}{k+p-1}$.  But this may not be an integer, so you may not have a winning move in step 4, and you will lose.  But the game was lost back in step 2 when you made the wrong choice for $s$.

Comment: where does the p+1-k come from exactly? I thought I could choose the exponent for v. I always set v equal to a single letter.

Comment: You get to choose the exponent for $v$ in step 4, that's $i$.  But before you get to do that, Mr. Pumping lemma gets to pick what $v$ is, in step 3.  So suppose he picks $\def\a{\mathtt{a}}u=\a^k$; that is, $u$ is some of the initial `a`s. And suppose he picks $v$ to be the rest of the `a`s.  You said that the string $w$ had $p+1$ `a`s, so if $u$ contains $k$ of them, then $v$ contains the rest, which is $p+1-k$ `a`s.

Comment: yeah... it's kinda confusing. are you saying it should work for any v? i thought that was completely irrelevant and i just had to make a string that was not in the language defined, so i would just set w such that i would just need to pump v once.

Comment: You don't get to pick $v$.  Mr. Pumping Lemma takes your string $s$ and cuts it into three parts,  $u,v,$ and $w$. Then you have to be able to show that *no matter how he cuts up* $s$, you can always come up with an $i$ that will make $uv^iw$ not part of $\mathscr L$.

Comment: actually, i just need to set it up like you did with all the variables, and make sure the condition is not met, right? this works for any problem of the same type, right?

Comment: also how would you make sure you would get an integer?

Comment: Well, that's the tricky part, isn't it?  If you pick $a^{p+1}b^p$, you can't make sure you get an integer, which is why that was a bad choice.  Which was your question.

Comment: i actually know the answer because it was in the book, but i don't know understand why it works and the rationale behind it. i think it was n! and (n+!)!... also, would a^nb^(n+1) work in most other cases? i wish there was more examples in the book... lol